# WPF Set Static Resource At Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set the style of a button at runtime using a static resource? The xaml looks like this:

```
<Button  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,0,1,0" 
                     Background="{StaticResource OrangeGradient}"  FontFamily="Lucida Sans"  BorderBrush="Black" >
```

What would the `Background="{StaticResource OrangeGradient}"` look like in c# at runtime?

My Resource dictionary, Resources/Styles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myProj">

<LinearGradientBrush  x:Key="OrangeGradient" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE08A19" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA86" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="myProj.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myProj"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml"   />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Comment: StaticResource can not be changed at runtime, use DynamicResource instead!

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want to change the resource definition, just apply it to the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analog of setting `Background` to static resource, but at runtime is just:

```
yourButton.Background = (Brush)this.Resources["OrangeGradient"];
```

Where `Resources` is `ResourceDictionary` with target brush, for example root `ResourceDictionary` of your `Window` or `UserControl`.

Comment: How can I access a resource dictionary in my `App.xaml` file?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg using `System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources`